# How to search Google places api and private database simultaneously

Tags: android, google-places-api

The most explanations on how to use the [Google places api](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/) is about using [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) or [Place Picker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker). I have a database containing places data and would like to use the the [Google places api](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/) like this:

User type location data into an Android `EditText` this will trigger a search both at [Google places api](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/) and internally at my database.

The result of user action is a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) containing both result from [Google places api](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/) and from my database.

How can I do this?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830) - inside `runQuery` method call places API followed by your local sqlite query and concatenate the results into `MatrixCursor` or `MergeCursor`

Comment: and if you still want the result to be shown in `RecyclerView` then use [ths](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter as a base class instead of `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: Thanks this was interesting. I see now I should have mention that my database is Cloud Firestore and not as I wrote "internally at my database" , MY BAD :)

Comment: doesnt matter - `runQuery` is called in the background thread so you can get your data from any sources - from the cloud too

Comment: I think the `CursorRecyclerAdapter` you link to could be rehacked for Firestore, Instead of init it with a `Cursor` init it with a Firestore CollectionReference

Comment: Yes grate news Thanks

Comment: but what about `Google places api` results? with `Cursor` interface you can combine both sources with `MatrixCursor`

Comment: Just tried your `MatrixCursor` code (answer)you link to, in a Android Studio project. Really smart using the wikipedia like this for illustration. Do you mean I should inside the `runQuery` search both Google Places Api and my Firestore database? Yes of course I see

Comment: its the easiest solution i think, do you really need `RecyclerView` or you can use `ACTV` (like in my code i posted)?

Comment: I think i need a ListView type since the result is both Firestore and Places Api. Maybe just suppress the `ACTV` drop down and populate a recycle view with the result. User can then press each row for selection. What you think. Your MatrixCursor `ACTV` is providing a good mechanism

Comment: ok if you need multi selection so you cannot use `ACTV` and you need `CursorRecyclerAdapter` i posted in my second comment

Comment: thanks I will give it a go in my test Android Studio project

Comment: simply use `CursorRecyclerAdapter` as a base class, setup its `FilterQueryProvider` (or directly override `runQueryOnBackgroundThread` method) and call `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)` for data searching

Comment: Works grate, I just created the `FilterQueryProvider` and run the `adapter.getFilter().filter("Sweden")` and my `RecyclerView` gets populated.  But I need a way for the user to type so the `AutoCompleteTextView` might come in handy again what you think? `AutoCompleteTextView` will give data for the `adapter.getFilter().filter("Sweden")` something..

Comment: for `ACTV` to work you dont have to call `adapter.getFilter().filter("Sweden")` - it is called automagically as you type anything in `ACTV`

Comment: Yes i know what I mean is when I use the `CursorRecyclerAdapter` I need a way to insert into `adapter.getFilter().filter()` from an  `EditText` or maybe from the `ACTV`

Comment: I would use SearchView - most likely in action bar, see SearchView.OnQueryTextListener - you can call `filter(...)` from `onQueryTextChange` and / or `onQueryTextSubmit` methods